# How to ssh to a linux server behind corporate firewall?

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall, remote-access

My company has a linux server (CentOS 6 VM) behind a corporate firewall, I have full root control of the VM, but I have no control over the firewall. There's an ssh server running on it, and I can ssh to it within the company network.

I would like to ssh to this VM when I'm outside of the company network. How do I achieve this?

This linux VM is running on a Mac host machine, which I can use logmein to connect, and then access the linux VM. I'd like to ssh directly to the linux VM.

I'm guessing there has to be some sort of handshake initiated by the linux VM to the outside machine for this to work?

Comment: Are you sure your company doesn't have a VPN setup for external access already?

Comment: Did you mean to post the same question, at the same time, to http://serverfault.com/questions/300380 ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [Hamachi](http://www.logmein.com). No opening of ports required for secure VPN tunnels. Use SSH through the VPN.

> LogMeIn Hamachi is a hosted VPN service that lets you securely extend LAN-like networks to distributed teams, mobile workers and your gamer friends alike. In minutes.

Comment: I tried hamachi actually, but was hit with an error: hamachi: /lib/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by hamachi)

Comment: make sure that you have installed build-essential and lsb

Answer (score 7):

The very best solution is to contact your network administrator and ask them to either open a TCP port for you in the firewall, or get a VPN connection to the network.

If you use any method that circumvents security (there are many out there, some of which are advertised on television in a way that makes it sound like a perfectly innocent thing to do), you could be at risk of losing your job, so make sure you go through the proper channels within the company to first obtain permission.

Maintaining internal network security is very important because companies have a legal responsibility to protect privacy.

Comment: +1... if you don't control the firewall, then someone else does, and they should be aware that you are doing this.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a ssh tunnel from `behindvpn` to `outsidevpn` host.

```
behindvpn$ ssh -R 1234:localhost:22 outsidevpn
```

This will open port `1234` on `outsidevpn` host which will forward connections to port `22` on the `behindvpn` host.

Now you can connect to `behindvpn` host with:

```
$ ssh outsidevpn -p 1234
```

**Note:** You may need to make sure that your connection will not break for example due to inactivity or shell timeout.